# Decompiling Protected APK

Tags: java, android

I have an old device that is controlled via Bluetooth with a Chinese android app that has since been discontinued. The device doesn't have any brand name and I have no clue what is the name of the company that manufactured it or who developed the app. All I have is the device and the original apk.

I have been playing around with APK decompilers but I ran into a dead-end because the apk seems to be protected. After decoding, I found 3 java classes (A.java, StubApplication.java and StubProvider.java) and a library called baiduprotect.jar which I assume was used to protect the app against decoding.

Recompiling the decompiled material doesn't work. What are my chances of figuring out what the APK does? My final goal is to make my bluetooth device work again (no longer supported) instead of throwing it to the trash.

Comment: Did you try this tool https://ibotpeaches.github.io/Apktool/

Comment: 1. describe your bluetooth device
2. if decompiling an apk was that easy then android would had run out of business

Comment: what you're trying to do doesn't sound very legal, but I'm no lawyer though...

Comment: @lelloman I'm not sure either but since I can't really find a trace of who build this, I suppose it is abandonware.

Comment: @Enzokie that is a) a very sad truth that with all the shit about the "Internet of Things" all we are going to get is 100 times more cyber trash each time a new startup disappears and doesn't publish their code for others to build upon it...

Comment: You really need to spend on the device with a Good reputation already. It's  a much better deal (Money wise ;) ). Though I have also tab from China with no more supports from the manufacturer and ended the last update to Icecream sandwich.

Comment: @Enzokie Even well know brands can fail :) And it's not uncommon for big brands to stop support after just a few years

Comment: try this free apk decompiler tool for free https://www.unboxapk.com. I personally use this tool, because there are multiple online tools available but they are not as much reliable.

Answer (score 1):

I do not care why you need this tools but i use them some time **to analyze projects similar to the app i'm trying to build**. But i have no idea to customize , rebuild and lunch them.

anyway: 
http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk

and 
http://www.decompileandroid.com/

Mostly they work for me.

Comment: UNBOXAPK https://www.unboxapk.com is the one of best tool for apk decompiler. please try for once.